# Oracle Data Integrator SQL to HDFS IKM returns error

Tags: oracle, hdfs, sqoop, oracle-data-integrator

I am using ODI (12.1.3.0.0). I created topology for Oracle DB which is OK and I created topology for HDFS using File technology where I think the problem is in.

DataServer for HDFS, I left JDBC driver empty, and filled JDBC Url with hdfs://remotehostname:port

Physical Schema for HDFS, I filled both Schema and Work Schema with /my/path

Then created Logical Schema and Model. After that created Datastore under the model with these definitions.
Name: TestName
Resource Name: TESTFILE.txt
File Format: Fixed

After all these, created a project and a mapping under the project.

[image: Mapping]

Finally when I run the mapping I see these errors:

```
ODI-1217: Session Oracle2HDFSMapping_Physical_SESS (15) fails with return code ODI-1298.
ODI-1226: Step Physical_STEP fails after 1 attempt(s).
ODI-1240: Flow Physical_STEP fails while performing a Add execute to Sqoop script-IKM SQL to HDFS File (Sqoop)- operation. This flow loads target table null.
ODI-1298: Serial task "SERIAL-MAP_MAIN- (10)" failed because child task "SERIAL-EU-GGUSER_UNIT (20)" is in error.
ODI-1298: Serial task "SERIAL-EU-GGUSER_UNIT (20)" failed because child task "Add execute to Sqoop script-IKM SQL to HDFS File (Sqoop)- (40)" is in error.
Caused By: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "chmod": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.cmd.OSCommandExecutor.execute(OSCommandExecutor.java:54)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.cmd.OSCommandExecutor.execute(OSCommandExecutor.java:29)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.TaskExecutionHandler.handleTask(TaskExecutionHandler.java:52)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.SessionTask.processTask(SessionTask.java:203)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.SessionTask.doExecuteTask(SessionTask.java:114)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.AbstractSessionTask.execute(AbstractSessionTask.java:886)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.SessionExecutor$SerialTrain.runTasks(SessionExecutor.java:2198)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.SessionExecutor.executeSession(SessionExecutor.java:591)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.TaskExecutorAgentRequestProcessor$1.doAction(TaskExecutorAgentRequestProcessor.java:718)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.TaskExecutorAgentRequestProcessor$1.doAction(TaskExecutorAgentRequestProcessor.java:611)
    at oracle.odi.core.persistence.dwgobject.DwgObjectTemplate.execute(DwgObjectTemplate.java:203)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.TaskExecutorAgentRequestProcessor.doProcessStartAgentTask(TaskExecutorAgentRequestProcessor.java:800)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.impl.StartSessRequestProcessor.access$1400(StartSessRequestProcessor.java:74)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.impl.StartSessRequestProcessor$StartSessTask.doExecute(StartSessRequestProcessor.java:702)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.task.AgentTask.execute(AgentTask.java:180)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.support.DefaultAgentTaskExecutor$2.run(DefaultAgentTaskExecutor.java:108)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:385)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:136)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 20 more
```

I wonder where I did it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For a file Datastore, you need to define the attributes (columns) by opening the Datastore and going on the attribute tab. If the file already exists, you can reverse-engineer the attributes and rename them and change the datatype if needed.

The error message you received for the second task mentions that the file (generated in the fist task) does not exist. So there might be a problem with the first task, probably due to the missing attributes in your datastore.

Here is a detailed article about SQL To HDFS file (Sqoop) KM written by the ODI A-Team : http://www.ateam-oracle.com/importing-data-from-sql-databases-into-hadoop-with-sqoop-and-oracle-data-integrator-odi/